# Lotus Domino Server on Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have an urgent paper to write on the best way to backup mails and database of over 500GB daily on a Lotus Domino Server (version 5.0.9) running on windows server 2003 for about 200 users. While limiting the amount of downtime.

Comment: "Urgent paper" ? Forgot about the assignment?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of backup software vendors offer clients for Domino which do not require downtime for backups.  Look into Tivoli Storage Manager and its associated Data Protection for Domino client.